# Jquery Form Validation works only once

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am using Jquery Form Validation as :

```
        $('#form').validate({
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block help-block-error', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "",  // validate all fields including form hidden input
        rules: {
            "cash": {
                equalTo: "#password"
            },

            "custFirstname": {
                required: true
            },
            "custLastname": {
                required: true
            },
            "custEmailaddress": {
                required: true,
                email: true,
            },
            "custmobileno": {
                required: true,
                minlength:9,
                maxlength:10,
                number: true
            },
            "adultFirstname[]": {
                required: () => {
                    return $("input[name='adultFirstname[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                }
            },
            "adultLastname[]":{
                    required: () =>{
                    return $("input[name='adultLastname[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                }
            },
            "adultDob[]": {
                required: () => {
                    return $("input[name='adultDob[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                },
                dateFormat:true

            },
            "adultPassportno[]": {
                required: () => {
                    return $("input[name='adultPassportno[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                },
            },

         "childFirstname[]": {
                required: () => {
                    return $("input[name='childFirstname[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                },
            },
            "childLastname[]": {
                required: () => {
                    return $("input[name='childLastname[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                },
            },
            "childDob[]": {
                required:() =>{
                    return $("input[name='childDob[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                },
                dateFormat:true
            },
            "childPassportno[]": {
                required: () => {
                    return $("input[name='childPassportno[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                },
            },

             "infantFirstname[]": {
                required: () => {
                    return $("input[name='infantFirstname[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                },
            },
            "infantLastname[]": {
                required: () => {
                    return $("input[name='infantLastname[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                },
            },
            "infantDob[]": {
                required: () => {
                    return $("input[name='infantDob[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                },
                dateFormat:true
            },
            "infantPassportno[]": {
                required: () => {
                    return $("input[name='infantPassportno[]']").filter(function() {
                        return $.trim($(this).val()).length > 0
                    }).length == 0
                },
            },
        },
        invalidHandler: (event, validator) => {
            $(".errorfield").hide();
            _.each(validator.errorList, (e: any) => {
                if (e.method == "equalTo") {
                    alert("Payment Gateway is not available please select Points only")

                }
                else if (e.method == "greaterThan") {
                    var confirm = $(".bs-example-modal-sm");
                    confirm.modal('show');
                    $('.modal-body').html(e.message);
                }
                else
                    $(e.element).parent().find("p").text(e.message).show();

            });             

        },

        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
            var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
            icon.removeClass('fa-check').addClass("fa-warning");
            //icon.attr("data-original-title", error.text()).tooltip({ 'container': 'body' });
        },

        highlight: function(element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element)
                .closest('.form-group').removeClass("has-success").addClass('has-error'); // set error class to the control group   
        },

        unhighlight: function(element) { // revert the change done by hightlight

        },

        success: (label, element) => {
            //$(element).parent().find("p").hide();
            var icon = $(element).parent('.input-icon').children('i');
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success'); // set success class to the control group
            icon.removeClass("fa-warning").addClass("fa-check");
        },

    });
```

when the form's submit button is clicked for the first time, it validates the form well but if we click again on the submit button it goes for form submission without any validation.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: go to the console and see if any error was triggered

Answer (score 0):

Prior filling to form, that is on form load, reset the form. Because it is taking the values from cache.